# grep with ^ (caret) doesn't work in the first line

Tags: regex, utf-8, grep

I would like to catch all section part with 'grep' command. However, I can't match my expression to the file in the first line but does well in the other line. I found the problem may be related to the file type but I don't know how to solve it if I'm not allowed to modify the file type. I'm begging for a solution.Thanks.

```
$> file test.ini
test.ini: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text

$> cat test.ini
[isp_info]
reg_img_widthm1 = 100
[isp_blc0]
reg_blc_enable = 0
[isp_dpc0]
reg_dpc_enable = 0

$> grep '^\[.*]$' test.ini
[isp_blc0]
[isp_dpc0]
```

However

```
$> file test.ini.ascii
test.ini.ascii: ASCII text

$> cat test.ini.ascii
[isp_info]
reg_img_widthm1 = 100
[isp_blc0]
reg_blc_enable = 0
[isp_dpc0]
reg_dpc_enable = 0

$> grep '^\[.*]$' test.ini.ascii
[isp_info]
[isp_blc0]
[isp_dpc0]
```

Comment: shouldn't you escape the second `]`?

Comment: What if you match the BOM as an optional sequence? `grep -E $'^(\xEF\xBB\xBF)?\[.*]$' file`?

Comment: may be there are characters at end of line of first line for the first case, try `cat -e test.ini`

Comment: it works well using `grep -E $'^(\xEF\xBB\xBF)?\[.*]$'` could you explain it for me?

Comment: `$> cat -e test.ini` shows `M-oM-;M-?[isp_info]$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If do not mind the BOM included in the first result, you may add an optional BOM pattern at the start of the regex:

```
grep -E $'^(\xEF\xBB\xBF)?\[.*]$' file
```

Or BRE POSIX compliant:

```
grep $'^\(\xEF\xBB\xBF\)\{0,1\}\[.*]$' file
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\xEF\xBB\xBF)?` (= `\(\xEF\xBB\xBF\)\{0,1\}` BRE) - an optional sequence of UTF8 BOM symbols
- `\[` -  a `[`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of the line

Alternatively, [remove BOM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381263/279389) and run your `grep` command:

```
sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' file | grep '^\[.*]$'
```